# Node server taking too much time to start the server in windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, npm

When I started the node server for running the react app. It didn't start and took very long. Sometimes it wont start.

I use the command to start the server:

```
npm start dev
```

This is my Package.json code:

```
{
  "name": "ABCD",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "abcd",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node backend/server",
    "server": "nodemon backend/server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix frontend",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "author": "XYZ",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: In my windows system, it takes about 30 sec